# TS2322: Type 'Count' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new in react and TS and I need help
I am trying to use useState with typescript

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

interface Count{
  count: number
}
const App = () =>{
  const [count,setCount] = useState<Count>(
    {
      count:0
    })
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Count <span>{count}</span> </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is currently an object. This is uncommon in react function components (since you can call `useState` as many times as you need to), so unless there's a reason to do it with an object, i would recommend making it a number:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Or with an explicit type:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
```

If you do need your state to be an entire object, then make sure to pluck out the number and put that on the page, not the full object:

```
<span>{count.count}</span>
```

Comment: thank you so much. I dont know how I do this kind of still mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `{count.count}` as `count` is an object (`{count:0}`)

```
<div>Count <span>{count.count}</span> </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. It was such a silly mistake